# PHPMailer - Getting Errorcode 500 and wrong paths, but cant figure out why. - How to fix the required Paths?

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2, phpmailer

So first of all, i used my code on my localhost with XAMPP and everything worked fine, so I decided to swap it over to my Server. (Deb10)
And now it just throws an error (500)
Im gonna provide my mailer.php class & the apache error logs in the following.

I have no idea where the error comes from.
Since I just coppied the files from my Win-PC i thought it might has something to do with it, so I tried to fix it with just coding those lines aggain, but on the Server.
Still getting this "Path error"

mailer.php

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer/PHPMailer/PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer/PHPMailer/Exception;

    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php'; // Path to Exception.php
    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php'; // Path to PHPMailer.php
    require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php'; // Path to SMTP.php



    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $discord = $_POST['discord'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];
    $languages = $_POST['languages'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP Server Host
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'secret'; // SMTP Server Email
        $mail->Password = '******'; // SMTP Server Email Password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom($email);
        $mail->addAddress('secret'); // Recipient Email

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Staff Application - '. $name;
        $mail->Body    = 'A user has filled out the form to apply to join the staff, below are all the details provided by the user.<br><br> >> <strong>In-game name:</strong> '. $name .'<br> >> <strong>Discord username:</strong> '. $discord .'<br> >> <strong>Email address:</strong> '. $email .'<br> >> <strong>Declared age:</strong> '. $age .'<br> >> <strong>DropDown:</strong>'. $dropdown .'<br> >> <strong>Country:</strong> '. $country .'<br> >> <strong>Language(s):</strong> '. $languages .'<br><br>Replying to this email will send a message to the email address entered in the form by the user.';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Thank You! Your mail has been sent.';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Oops! Something went wrong and we coud not send your application. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
?>
```

And the error from the Apache2 logs:

```
[Mon May 30 00:00:48.274395 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 238] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 00:00:48.274454 2022] [core:notice] [pid 238] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 07:54:18.367455 2022] [authz_core:error] [pid 36552] [client 46.101.237.85:35724] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html
[Mon May 30 12:09:37.868613 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 238] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:09:38.095956 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20036] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:09:38.096058 2022] [core:notice] [pid 20036] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:23:24.527454 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20036] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:23:24.830499 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26335] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:23:24.830657 2022] [core:notice] [pid 26335] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:26:09.751698 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26335] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:26:10.022203 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27566] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:26:10.022335 2022] [core:notice] [pid 27566] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:28:56.135213 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27566] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:28:56.339343 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28759] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:28:56.339458 2022] [core:notice] [pid 28759] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:31:44.950761 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28759] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:31:45.699579 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30335] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:31:45.699697 2022] [core:notice] [pid 30335] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:32:54.676200 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30335] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:32:54.811111 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30874] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:32:54.811240 2022] [core:notice] [pid 30874] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:33:59.819728 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30874] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:34:00.095530 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31392] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:34:00.095667 2022] [core:notice] [pid 31392] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 12:45:07.493948 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31392] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon May 30 12:45:07.637058 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 36340] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 30 12:45:07.637181 2022] [core:notice] [pid 36340] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 30 13:06:44.877628 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36968] [client 89.247.168.43:21544] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:06:44.884356 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36968] [client 89.247.168.43:21544] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:06:52.274916 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36342] [client 89.247.168.43:21550] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:06:52.275026 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36342] [client 89.247.168.43:21550] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:06:52.881658 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 40306] [client 89.247.168.43:21551] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:06:52.881736 2022] [php7:error] [pid 40306] [client 89.247.168.43:21551] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:07:05.772104 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 40289] [client 89.247.168.43:21553] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5
[Mon May 30 13:07:05.772178 2022] [php7:error] [pid 40289] [client 89.247.168.43:21553] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5
[Mon May 30 13:07:58.526909 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36341] [client 89.247.168.43:21556] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:07:58.526978 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36341] [client 89.247.168.43:21556] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:11:36.308336 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36511] [client 89.247.168.43:21577] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:11:36.308393 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36511] [client 89.247.168.43:21577] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:11:37.095348 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36967] [client 89.247.168.43:21578] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:11:37.095404 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36967] [client 89.247.168.43:21578] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:11:38.111411 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36343] [client 89.247.168.43:21579] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://host/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:11:38.111464 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36343] [client 89.247.168.43:21579] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5, referer: http://31.214.245.36/buildit/
[Mon May 30 13:12:24.076918 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 36968] [client 89.247.168.43:21584] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5
[Mon May 30 13:12:24.076974 2022] [php7:error] [pid 36968] [client 89.247.168.43:21584] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5
[Mon May 30 13:12:38.855562 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 40305] [client 89.247.168.43:21592] PHP Warning:  require(Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5
[Mon May 30 13:12:38.855621 2022] [php7:error] [pid 40305] [client 89.247.168.43:21592] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Z:\\XAMPP\\Composer\\vendor\\phpmailer\\phpmailer\\src\\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php on line 5
```

Comment: Where is `mailer.php` located relative to the things you try to `require`?

Comment: It looks like you're using composer to fetch your dependencies, but not using it to actually load them. Halfway there!

Comment: @geertjanknapen mailer.php is located in ../var/www/html/buildit/mailer.php while the phpmailer is located in ../root/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/

Comment: @Synchro What do you mean by that? I'm pretty new to composer and stuff, but I thought all I need to do is the 'require' and the 'use', since this was the way it worked on windows.

Comment: You might be using Composer to fetch your libraries but, if you don't have anything similar to `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` to let PHP load them automatically, you'll still need lots of manual work. The `use` keyword is used to save some typing, it doesn't really have anything to do with Composer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Aight so I might need to understand how to use the autoload.
But I still dont get the Pathing errors, since these Paths showing up on the error are never given.

Comment: There isn't much to learn if you only want to use third-party packages. Just include that single file.

Comment: you must check if the composer is installed on your server and there you have to do a `composer install` to create your vendor folder.

Comment: @Marco But i just have a vendor folder, but ill give it a shoot anyway.

Update: Output after Composer install 
`Nothing to install, update or remove`

Comment: seems that you habe copied the vendor folder from your localhost. Try to remove the vendor folder from the server and after that the composer install.

Comment: You don't need SSH access or any specific support in your hosting service. Composer produces regular files, which you can deploy with the rest of your code, there's hardly any magic involved.